# How do I get multi-image file after rotating one frame using SelectActiveFrame?

Tags: c#

I have a file that has multiple images and I can select a frame and rotate it but I am not able to save that multi-image file with one frame being rotated.

```
using (MemoryStream memSt = new MemoryStream(Bytes)) 
{ myImage = Image.FromStream(memSt); 
  myImage.SelectActiveFrame(frameDimensions, frameNum); //frameNUm = 2 second frame
  myImage.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
}
```

so here I rotate a selected frame. Now how do I get the image file with all the images in it and frame 2 being rotated. If I save and return myImage it would just be a file with just one frame the one I rotated.

Answer (score 0):

It's non-intuitive and a bit tedious, but you have to save a new image using [`Image.Save`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.save?view=windowsdesktop-7.0), then add each frame of your modified image to that image file using the [`Image.SaveAdd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.saveadd) method.

The documentation for `SaveAdd` explains it a little:

> Adds a frame to the file or stream specified in a previous call to the
> Save method. Use this method to save selected frames from a
> multiple-frame image to another multiple-frame image.